# Hyper-V virtual network switch

Tags: networking, hyper-v

So this might be a very basic and very stupid question but for the life of me I can not find an explanation on the web anywhere as to how this should work.

I have a very basic Hyper-V setup on my Windows 10 machine. I have two VM's one is a Mikrotik image and the other is lUbuntu. At this point I'm working on the most basic network configuration. I want the Mikrotik to behave as a router and firewall between the lUbuntu system and the outside.

I have two virtual network switches (VS) setup in Hyper-V. First the default switch (call it Outside) and second an internal switch (call it Inside) I created. The Mikrotik box has two VNIC's setup that are connected to the two switches. It acts as a DHCP-server on the VNIC which is connected to the Inside VNS.

If I look at my Host system (the Windows 10 I'm running the Hyper-V on) I see the expected two virtual switches as NIC's one vEthernet (Inside) and one vEthernet (Outside).

The issue I have is that the (Inside) NIC has a APIPA address. When I try to get it to renew the adress using ipconfig /renew the command times out. At the same time the Lubuntu system which has one VNIC which is connected to the (Inside) VS works just fine and gets an IP address from the appropriate pool right away.

So my first question is why does the Host system not behave the way I would expect with regards to a Hyper-V Virtual switch?

I assumed from what I read about Hyper-V virtual switches that the Host operating system should see it pretty much the same as a guest. Except it knows it's virtual I guess.

Comment: You need something on the internal network providing IP addresses. Either static IPs on each client on this network, or a DHCP server.

Comment: @music2myear As the question states I have a Mikrotik router which is setup as a DHCP-server on the VNIC that is bound to the internal VS.

Comment: Either it is not providing the correct service, or the other VMs aren't finding that service.

Comment: @music2myear The VM's are finding the service just fine. The lUbuntu VM gets an IP address no problem. The issue is with the Host OS not the VM's.

Comment: One more question: If the purpose of the Internal switch is to allow communication between the VMs and to provide communication Lubuntu to the Mikrotik, why didn't you choose a Private switch? The Private switch allows communication only between the VMs on your host and so sounds like the correct switch for the job. An Internal switch generally acts as a bridge on your host, allowing VMs access to host resources, which is not what it sounds like you are trying to do with that particular switch.

Comment: @music2myear I understand the difference between a private switch and an internal switch. I would like to be able to communicate from the Host to the guests and vice versa. I don't quite understand what that has to do with why the Host doesn't seem to see the DHCP server on that NIC?

Comment: I have a similar setup, but am not running a DHCP server on my VM network. I just use static IPs because it's simpler and less likely to cause problems upstream if I have a misconfiguration. I have guesses as to why you're experiencing this, but research has not given any weight of proof to these guesses so far.

Comment: Is by any chance your IP net work from your physical router (the one your windows 10 DHCP's form) conflicting with the one your mikrotik is handing out? (ie. are they in the same network?)

Comment: Could you perhaps also port your DHCP settings in the mirkrotik?

Comment: @EdoPost That's a good question but no. They are on different subnets. 89 and 88.

Comment: @DRF I see you accepted the answer, I’m guessing it’s solved now

Comment: @EdoPost Yes. Thank you for the responses but it turned out to be an issue with having left a default VLAN for the management OS setup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**So you have . . .**

1. The VM Mikrotik machine configured with two NIC's with one
   connected to the "internal" Hyper-V switch (inside) that has the DHCP service running on it, and the other is connected to an "external" Hyper-V switch (outside), etc.
2. The lUbuntu VM has one NIC and you connect that to the "internal" Hyper-V switch which has a DHCP server service listening on it from the Mikrotik machine to process requests accordingly.

### Clarification Resources

**1. Configuring VM Networking on a Hyper-V NAT Switch**

- > Virtual machines that are connected to a NAT virtual switch are in an
  >   isolated broadcast domain, a different one to the LAN. The NAT switch
  >   does not have flat, 2-way routing to the LAN that the host is
  >   connected to. The virtual switch is an internal virtual switch that
  >   the host NATs to the LAN. This means that, by default, the virtual
  >   machines can connect to the LAN, but the LAN cannot connect to the
  >   virtual machines. And even if we do create NAT rules, the virtual
  >   switch remains a separate broadcast domain from the LAN.
  >
  > The virtual switch is somewhat isolated from the LAN, especially from broadcast-based services such as DHCP. You can deploy your own DHCP server(s) as virtual machines that are connected to the virtual switch. The scope of these servers is limited to the virtual switch, so there is no impact on the LAN, and network administrators should not have a problem with your DHCP servers being deployed on the NAT virtual switch.
  >
  > [Source](https://www.petri.com/configuring-vm-networking-hyper-v-nat-switch)

**2. Internal Hyper-V switch configuration**

- > **Internal**:  Allows communication between virtual machines on the same Hyper-V server, and between the virtual machines and the
  >   management host operating system.
  >
  > [Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/get-started/create-a-virtual-switch-for-hyper-v-virtual-machines)

**3. Visualization of all switch modes**

- > [image]
  >
  > [Source](https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/the-hyper-v-virtual-switch-explained-part-1/)

### Potential Workarounds

1. The way I've handled this is to ensure the VMs connected to the internal switch have IP addresses assigned, and then from the host Hyper-V management server, I then can access those machines from the host OS that way via their IP addresses.
2. You could probably look over the [Set up a NAT network](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/setup-nat-network), and be sure to have a full understanding of it and then **Create a NAT virtual network** and configure it accordingly to see if it'll do what you want using the "internal" Hyper-V switch functionality.
3. Since the VMs can talk with the Mikrotik machine, perhaps you can setup routing in it and then tell the VMs to use it's accessible internal Hyper-V switch IP address as the default gateway on all those devices, and just let it do the routing when things need accessed that's not connected to the internal Hyper-V switch.
4. Check your VLAN configuration and see [Configure virtual local area networks for Hyper-V](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/deploy/configure-virtual-local-areal-networks-for-hyper-v) in the event something at this level is needed or causing trouble.

   - [Configure and View VLAN Settings on Hyper-V Virtual Switch Ports](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v-virtual-switch/configure-and-view-vlan-settings-on-hyper-v-virtual-switch-ports)
5. Check any OS level firewall rules for the blocking of the traffic coming from the internal Hyper-V switch to the host Hyper-V or any of the connected VMs.

Comment: Hmm I think the conclusion is incorrect though the information is certainly interesting. Notice that the picture you provide shows the Internal switch being connected to a specific (virtual)NIC in the Host OS. This seems important especially in the case where you are running the Hyper-V on a Windows-10 machine (I believe that's called client Hyper-V?) in which case the first part of that picture is actually wrong. Or rather misleading since the "Default switch" is none of those three. It behaves as explained in part 1.

Comment: That means that the "Default switch" actually performs NAT on things coming in from the outside. I don't (yet) know what that means for Host to Guest communication on this switch but it's (probably) not the same as the External switch where the Host OS will have an IP address in the same pool as the VM's and all of these will behave as if they are behind a switch which then is connected to the outside through the Physical Network card.

Comment: (Note I have actually already figured out where my issue was with the help of a friend. Specifically I messed up the VLAN's on the Host NIC. I put the Host OS into Vlan 2. Disabling "Vlan identification for management operating system" fixed my issue. And the VNIC in the Host OS now gets and IP address from the Mikrotik DHCP server without issues. So you're exactly right in your comment there was another level of blocking.

Comment: @DRF I re-read that statement and I also agree it was not correct so I purged that content from the answer. I also added some additional detail and resources that may be helpful with regard to the VLAN level stuff and the other levels of blocking such as OS level firewalls and such.